# creating export task in aws cloudwatch log

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, command-line-interface

I am trying to create export task for moving the cloudwatch logs more than 30 day to move to s3 bucket. I am currently following this AWS article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html. I am stuck with the creation of export task. when I ran the below command

```
 aws logs create-export-task --profile CWLExportUser --task-name "my-log-group-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" --log-group-name "/aws/lambda/AMICreate" --from  60  --to  155520000 --destination "diego-cw-logs" --destination-prefix "export-task-output"
```

I am getting below error

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateExportTask operation: Specified time range of '60' and '155520000' is not valid. Please make sure the values are within the retention period of the log groups and from value is lesser than the to values
```

I am missing something. It would be great if some one render their hands to fix the issue.

Warmly,
Muneesh

Answer (score 2):

Use https://currentmillis.com/ to convert time in milisecond. Below is python code and use it with eventbridge to get transfer log as per your need.

import json
import boto3
import botocore
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def hello(event, context):

```
# Date calculated in milisecond
time_seven_days_ago = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-103)).timestamp()
time_six_days_ago = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-102)).timestamp()
print(int(time_seven_days_ago)*1000) #printing to CloudWatch
print(int(time_six_days_ago)*1000) #printing to CloudWatch

#Boto3 objecets for CW and SNS
client = boto3.client('sns')
cli = boto3.client('logs')

try:
    response = cli.create_export_task(
    taskName='task-name',logGroupName='cloudwatch-log-group-name', fromTime=int(time_seven_days_ago)*1000, to=int(time_six_days_ago)*1000,  destination='s3-bucket-name',   destinationPrefix='its-your-wish')
    print(response)
    client.publish(
        TopicArn='topic--arn',
        #Sending Error in Email
        Message='Task completed',
        Subject='Create Task Job Status',
        MessageStructure='Create Task Job status'
        )

except BaseException as error:
    print('Error From Lambda Function', error) #Printing Error to CloudWatch
    try:
        client.publish(
        TopicArn='topic-arn',
        #Sending Error in Email
        Message=error,
        Subject='Create Task Job Failed',
        MessageStructure='Create Task Job Failed'+error
        )
    except BaseException as fail:
        print('Error while sending email', fail)
```

Answer (score 1):

`--to` and `--from` [should be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/create-export-task.html):

> The start time of the range for the request, expressed as the number of **milliseconds** after Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC

In your case you are using `--from  60  --to  155520000` which means that you want to export values from 60 millseconds after `1970 00:00:00` to 155520000 milliseconds after (~two days) after. Obviously this does not make sense.

So basically you have to provide correct **timestamps in milliseconds** for the range you want to use.

Comment: Hi @Marcin..thankyou for the prompt response..still I couldnot get the logic....My log group creation time is 1601800161275. and i need to move it to s3 after 30 days..then what should be my --from and --to..it would be great help.

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi You can't move them in the future. Have to way 30 days, and them move `--from today-30days` `--to today`.

Comment: oh got it..thankyou ...i dont find any useful link to provide from and to ...cant we give hours??? it is not taking the way you gave above

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi I gave you the link in my answer. You have to use `timestamps in milliseconds`, not hours.